# C# поиск текста между тегами

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения, текст, выборка

добрый день, перелазил в гугле уже, но не смог найти ответа на свой вопрос, извиняюсь если он слишком глупый, но надеюсь, что кто-то сможет помочь.

документ, содержание которого в виде

```
//----- (00000001) --------------------------------------------------------

some text

//----- (00000002) --------------------------------------------------------

some text2

//----- (00000003) --------------------------------------------------------
```

я хочу найти способ, что-бы вытащить всё содержимое между

```
//----- (00000001) --------------------------------------------------------

//----- (00000002) --------------------------------------------------------
```

где числа в скобах являются ключем: задаю аргумент к примеру 00000005 и нужно получить всё, что находится на строках начиная с той, где будет найдено `(00000005)` и до следующего набора символов `//-----`

если мы подаём

```
//----- (00000001) --------------------------------------------------------
some text2
//----- (00000002) --------------------------------------------------------
some text3
some text4
//----- (00000003) --------------------------------------------------------
```

и аргумент `00000002` то на выходе получить

```
//----- (00000002) --------------------------------------------------------
some text3
some text4
```

пытаюсь сделать на c#, но пока что никак не могу понять, как получить все строки " от и до "

никак не могу понять какое выражение ставить с учетом условий задачи для Regex.Match(**)

как аргумент для поиска идёт `static string testArg = "00000001";`

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (var outputFile = new StreamWriter(String.Format("output.c")))
    {
        StreamReader file = new StreamReader("test.c");
        string line;
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            string matchText = Regex.Match(line, "((.*)//-----)").Value;

            outputFile.WriteLine("{0}", matchText);
        }
    }
}
```

а вот как этот аргумент поиска применить тут не могу найти;

Comment: У вас именно такие теги? Если формат один из стандартных, то лучше воспользоваться готовым парсером.

Comment: Если вы парсите email attachment, то опять-таки лучше не изобретать велосипед.

Answer (score 2):

Автору наверное ответ уже не нужен. Но так как я сегодня потратил пол дня на тестирование различных регулярных выражений в решении данной задачи (ради интереса). То может кому пригодится способ на регулярках:

```
// Допустим прочитаем файл с данными.
        using (StreamReader str = new StreamReader(@"d:\testTxt.txt", Encoding.Default))
        {
            string txtFile = str.ReadToEnd();
            // Ключ который необходимо найти и текст под ним до следующего ключа или конца строки.
            string findKey = "00000003";
            // Регулярное выражение.
            string regular = @"^//-{5} \(" + findKey + @"\) -{56}(?<txt>[^/]+(/[^/]*)*?)(^//-{5}|$)";
            Regex rx = new Regex(regular, RegexOptions.Multiline);
            Match m = rx.Match(txtFile);
            // Найденный текст идущий после искомого ключа.
            string foundText = m.Groups["txt"].Value;

            Console.WriteLine(foundText);
        }
```

При тестировании небольшого файла в цикле из 100000 итераций время - 1c 67мс. Это достаточно быстро.

При использовании стандартной регулярки с использованием минимального квантификатора к точке - ~ 45сек.

```
string regular = @"//-{5} \(" + searchNumber + @"\) -{56}(?<txt>.+?)(?://-{5})|$";
Regex rx = new Regex(regular, RegexOptions.Singleline);
Match m = rx.Match(txtFile);                
string foundText = m.Groups["txt"].Value;
```

а если использовать положительный поиск и обратный положительный вместо сохраняющих скобок то вовсе программа зависает на 2,5 мин.

Answer (score 1):

Один из вариантов:

```
string testArg = "00000002";
string pattern = @"//-+\s+\(" + testArg + @"\)\s+-+.*?(?=//-+)";
string text = File.ReadAllText("file.txt");            

var options = RegexOptions.Singleline;
string matchText = Regex.Match(text, pattern, options).Value;

Console.WriteLine(matchText);
```

Объяснение регулярки:
`//` - два символа `/`
`-+` - один или несколько символов `-`
`\s+` - один или несколько пробелов
`\(` - скобка, нужно её экранировать
Добавляем в шаблон нужное значение.
`\)` - закрывающая скобка
Опять один или несколько пробелов, один или несколько тире.
`.*?` - любые символы, в любом количестве (ноль или больше), не жадно, чтобы не захватить последующие комментарии. Именно они нам и нужны.
`(?= )` - позитивный просмотр вперёд (lookahead) - будет искать подходящий шаблон, но он не будет захвачен в результат.
`//-+` - то, что ищем в просмотре вперед.

`RegexOptions.Singleline` - этот параметр нужен, чтобы метасимвол . (точка) захватывал переводы строк.

Вообще, регулярку можно накручивать чуть-ли не бесконечно.
Например, чтобы в результат не попали символы перевода строки в конце, можно изменить шаблон просмотра вперёд:
`(?=\r\n//-+)`
Подразумевается, что в файле переводы строк в стиле Windows.

Если не нужно захватывать сам комментарий в начале, то воспользуемся позитивным просмотром назад (lookbehind):

```
string pattern = @"(?<=//-+\s+\(" + testArg + @"\)\s+-+\r\n).*?(?=\r\n//-+)";
```

---

Вариант без регулярки:

```
var resultLines = File.ReadLines("file.txt")
    .SkipWhile(s => !s.StartsWith("//----- (" + testArg)) // пропускаем строки, пока не встретится нужная
    .Skip(1) // пропускаем саму эту строку комментария
    .TakeWhile(s => !s.StartsWith("//----- (")) // берем строки до тех пор, пока не встретится опять комментарий
    ;

string resultText = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, resultLines);
Console.WriteLine(resultText);
```

Comment: Решение на основе регулярного выражения может не справиться с очень длинным текстом из-за ленивого кванитификатора, примененного к точке. Это очень неэффективно. А второе решение не включает в себя начальный `//----- (идентификатор) --------------------------------------------------------`.